# How do i throw custom response from Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We are using Custom Authentication providers for authenticating users. This providers will talk one of our services and validates the user(It's Basic Authentication).

Some times our internal Services could be down because of unknown reasons. In that case i would like to throw a custom response back to the user (500, "Internal Server Error").

We tried by throwing a custom Exception(Which extends Authentication Exception) and handling it at the Custom Authentication Entry Point.
But we see that the custom Exception is not propagated up. It's masked by some other exception(Access Denied Exception to be precise) by spring.

How do i get the custom exception thrown at the providers to Authentication Entrypoints, so that i would be able to discriminate and throw proper response.

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String userName = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    try{
        if (authenticationService.checkCredential(userName, password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userName, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new CustomAuthticationException("Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component
 public class MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements 
AuthenticationEntryPoint {
 @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException e)
          throws IOException, ServletException {

       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       System.out.println("In MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint");
       if(e.getCause() instanceof CustomAuthticationException){
        System.out.println("Custom Exception");
       }
    }   
  }
```

Comment: You can ControllerAdvice for throwing exception

Comment: Using ControllerAdvice did not help much, because authentication happens much earlier and the exception is thrown way earlier and it won't be catched by the exception resolver's.